# Mysql: get 'last' value inside a group for view

Tags: mysql, sql, group

*I have a table of RT data from devices (IOT), like this (say 't1'):*

```
 time*                  device   key       value
2022-08-20 12:00:12     a1       inp01     0.123
2022-08-20 12:00:15     a2       12        false
2022-08-20 12:00:25     a1       dev01     0.128
2022-08-20 12:00:50     a3       xk4       412  
more...
```

*My objectif (on MySQL 5.1.62) is to group and decimate the `t1` records, making a **view** like this, with a more usable record every 5 min (300s):*

```
 time*                inp01      xk4    ...*
2022-08-20 12:00:12   0.124      412    ...
2022-08-20 12:05:03   0.113      NULL   ...
2022-08-20 12:10:05   NULL       312    ...
more...
```

*I use a QUERY like this to get it:*

```
SELECT `time`,
 AVG(case when (`key` = 'inp01') then `value` end) AS `inp01`,
 MAX(case when (`key` = 'xk4') then `value` end) AS `xk4`,
  ...more...
FROM `t1`
WHERE ((`device` = 'a1') OR (`device` = 'a3')) 
 GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) DIV 300) 
 ORDERED BY `time`;
```

*that works as expected.*

Now the problem: on groups I can use `MAX(), AVG()`... but in some cases I would need a `FIST()` and a `LAST()` (of course order by 'time' or maybe an `HEAD()` and `TAIL()` if the set is ordered by ORDER BY).

I couldn't find a valid inspiration in the examples I found... does anyone have an idea ? (n.b.: I can not change the MySQL version, user-variables use is restricted in views).

Comment: For this purposes (get first/last value per group) on MySQL 5.1.62 you may use user-defined variables. Also, if `(time, key)` is defined as unique, you may use trivial limited subqueries. Alternatively you may use GROUP_CONCAT over needed column with needed ordering and extract the most first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTINE(300 * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) DIV 300)) AS `time`,
 AVG(case when (`key` = 'inp01') then `value` end) AS `inp01`,
 MAX(case when (`key` = 'xk4') then `value` end) AS `xk4`,
  ...more...

,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(case when (`key` = 'inp01') then `value` end ORDER BY `time` ASC), ',', 1) AS first_value_per_group_for_inp01
,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(case when (`key` = 'inp01') then `value` end ORDER BY `time` DESC), ',', 1) AS last_value_per_group_for_inp01
  ...more for another `key` values...

FROM `t1`
WHERE ((`device` = 'a1') OR (`device` = 'a3')) 
GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) DIV 300) 
ORDER BY `time`;
```

Comment: Many thanks Akina for the quick reply and the complete example. Tried, it works as expected. I think I'll use this: it seems simple (I understood it too!), And fast: perfect.